# angularjs: check length of filter in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

For example i have this repeat list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="suggestion-item" ng-repeat="item in suggestionList.items | filter: {id: 2} track by track(item)">{{item.text}}</li>
<ul>
```

Can i somehow (would be better without changing controller because it's a directive) check: if filter result is not empty - then display whole `ul`, if not, then hide `ul`. I mean something like:

```
<ul ng-if="(item in suggestionList.items | filter: {id: 2}).length > 0">
    <li class="suggestion-item" ng-repeat="item in suggestionList.items | filter: {id: 2} track by track(item)">{{item.text}}</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the filter result to a variable

```
<ul ng-show="filterResult && filterResult.length">
    <li class="suggestion-item" ng-repeat="item in filterResult = (suggestionList.items | filter: {id: 2}) track by track(item)">{{item.text}}</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

using **$parent** you can achieve it

```
<ul ng-show="suggestionListItem.length" >
 <li class="suggestion-item" ng-repeat="item in ($parent.suggestionListItem = (suggestionList.items | filter: {id: 2} track by track(item)))">{{item.text}}</li>
<ul>
```